# Creating an Array of Equally Spaced x and y Values - Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am attempting to make two arrays, one for the xValues and one for the yValues, of the coordinates of a set of equally spaced points given the amount of rows and columns. When displayed to the screen, only a few of the Sprites can be seen, suggesting these x and y arrays are incorrectly positioned. I'm not sure if it's the size of the sprite interfering (40x40), but any help would be appreciated.

```
CGFloat xSpacing = (sceneSize.height / (columnAmount-1)) ; 
CGFloat ySpacing = (sceneSize.width / (rowAmount-1)) ; 

CGFloat currentX = 0 ;
CGFloat currentY = 0 ;

for ( int i = 0 ; i < columnAmount ; i++ ) {

    currentX = currentX + xSpacing;
    [xValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentX]];

}

for (int i = 0 ; i < rowAmount ; i++ ) {

    currentY = currentY + ySpacing;
    [yValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentY]];

}
```

The position of each sprite in the level data is stored as a single digit value for x, and a single digit for y, each corresponding to that element of the above generated arrays.

```
    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(
                                   [[xValueArray objectAtIndex:[dictionary[@"xPosition"] intValue]] floatValue],
                                   [[yValueArray objectAtIndex:[dictionary[@"yPosition"] intValue]] floatValue]);
```

The dictionary you are seeing is an info.plist dictionary, the xPosition key values will range from 0-4, the yPosition key values will range from 0-2.

Comment: It would help if you showed the relevant code showing how you use the two arrays.

Comment: For start try logging all positions, that should give you a clue.

Comment: I've logged the positions; but I'm not entirely sure how the coordinate system works in sprite kit. Are the x, y values retained in landscape orientation, or does it automatically switch them? Some of the points I logged seemed like they should have been on the screen, but did not appear.